# Power Automate - I am trying to format a date, coming from an SQL database

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a Flow in Power Automate to retrieve data from an SQL database, and put that data into a Sharepoint calendar.

the Flow is:

1. Manually Trigger
2. (SQL) Get Rows (V2)
3. Compose action `formatDateTime(item()?['dato'],'dd-MM-yyyy')`
4. (Sharepoint ) Create Item.

It fails when i try to use the FormatDateTime function in the compose action, with the following error:

> InvalidTemplate
> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Compose' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'formatDateTime' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see `https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#formatdatetime` for usage details.

Screenshots of the Flow:

Entire Flow

[image]

Compose action that fails

[image]

Create Item, mapping fields

[image]

I hope someoen here is able to help me cause it feels like i'm close

What haven't i tried i've tried to solve this issue in al ot of different ways, i'll try to put some of them down here, as detailed as i can.
I am completey new to Power Automate so a lot of the different "solutions" comes from searching.

I have tried to put a another compose action in before the compose action that is supposed to format my date
and that one actually works.

Compose action with the "dato" from SQL

[image]

The result of the above compose action, it has 13 entries all of them succeeded

[image]

The whole issue with trying to format the date, came from the very beginning where i would just grab and map the "Dato" field from the SQL database directly in the (Sharepoint)Create Item.

But then i would get this error message on only 2 of the dates from "Dato"
So i thought i wouls just format all the date from "dato" just in case

I do get the first 4 entries into my sharepoint calendar but then i fails on the

OpenApiOperationParameterTypeConversionFailed
The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/StartDato' is required to be of type 'String/date'. The runtime value "17-01-2024" to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/date'.

If you want the outputs please tell, an i will post them but it's a lot of text.

Other than that i have tried different ways with "Initialize variable" and "compose" actions without luck

UPDATE:

It's always the same 2 dates 17-01-2024' and '16-01-2024' it's possible that it's really just those 2 dates i have to fix, they look normal in the database but might have gotten "corrupted" or something.

As for the rest of the dates they do get imported into the calendar.
But i am from Denmark working in IT on a school, and the dates i am trying to get into a sharepoint calendar comes from a database, that gets populated with data everytime a user fills out a form, where they request IT help for an event.

So the dates are coming in with the format dd-MM-yyyy and for all the dates with a "dd" under 12 they do go into the calendar but "dd" and "MM" are switched  around.
So 09-01-2024 becomes 01-09-2024 i want the first format.

so i need to find a way to keep the format as dd-MM-yyyy

[screenshot of the dates("dato") from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wgUl.png)
[screenshot from the sharepoint calendar(list)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTuon.png)

Comment: There is no "fix" to formatting a missing date (other than testing for it and not trying to format a missing date).  And `17-01-2024` is (apparently) not in a valid date format, so would need to be re-formatted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but isn't re-formatting also what i'm trying to accomplish with my question ?.
And also not sure how it can be "missing" when it is there ?

Comment: "The provided value is of type 'Null'" means the computer disagrees about the value being there.

Comment: Okay I guess I should just try and work with the date format I get. Thought it would make more sense to format the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue is that SharePoint doesn't recognize the date format `dd-MM-yyyy`.

Strongly suggest you use the ISO format of `yyyy-MM-dd` for passing dates to SharePoint (or most other connectors).

Update your flow back to the original and add the following to your `create item`:

```
formatDateTime(parseDateTime('14-01-2024', 'da', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Replace `'14-01-2024'` with the relevant expression from your DB date field.

Comment: Hey
Thank you for taking your time to help.

I tried it but is till gives me the error message:
**Unable to process template language expressions in action 'create_item' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'In function 'parseDateTime', the value provided for date time string '17-01-2024' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'.**

Comment: I updated my question with som information of what's happening after i run the Flow.

I couldn't fit it all in the comment

Comment: Update the answer above to include expected date format for the parse. If it doesn't work then please share the full expression you are using.

Comment: okay so i tried out the expression: 'formatDateTime(parseDateTime('14-01-2024', 'da', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')'

Comment: And? What was the result?

Comment: og yea sorry the result from running your expression as it was is that all 13 entries gets imported into the calendar but all on the same date like '14-01-2024'

an the result from this: `formatDateTime(parseDateTime(item()?['dato'], 'da', 'dd-MM-yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` was i must have done something wrong before but now it's fixed and it all working! all 13 entries with correct date and shit OMG thank you so MUCH!